# Опциональный параметр в роуте

Tags: php, laravel

Пробую сделать мультиязычный сайт на Laravel 5.3

```
Route::group( ['prefix'     => '{lang?}'], function () {
Route::get( '/{post}', 'Front\Post@index' )->name( 'post' );
Route::get( '/', 'Front\HomeController@index' )->name( 'home' );
} );
```

Если ссылка `/ru/some-post`, роут срабатывает правильно и вызывается контроллер `Front\Post@index`
Но если ссылка `/some-post` то роут считает что `some-post` - это параметр `lang`, а не `post`. 
Идея такова, что хочется прятать локализацию из url для языка по умолчанию.

Кто что может посоветовать по данному поводу?

Comment: Не использовать локализацию в URL либо не прятать дефолтную. Конечно эта группа слишком глобальна, она перекроет все роуты. Поверьте мне, "игра"  с роутами к хорошему не приведёт. В итоге можно такого навертеть, что потом непонятно будет куда что и зачем. :) Не усложняйте, рядовой пользователь вообще в URL не смотрит, ему на этот ru/en в адресной строке вообще плевать, а вы выбранный язык можете вполне хранить в сессии. Если нужна локализация для контекстной рекламы, то просто добавьте в ПО обработчик get параметров который будет отдавать нужный язык.

Comment: А как быть с SEO? Если у меня url один и тот же. только в зависимости от языка - идет приставка?

Comment: Поэтому, обычно, язык ставят в субдомен, так проще.